# Parse string based on occurrence of last charindex

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have the following strings:

```
Hello World (111)
Welcome to the World (GI 135) (222)
Another Hello World String (ID 12) (141) (333)
```

where I need to parse out the values in the last parentheses, so the output would be:

```
111
222
333
```

I am not sure how to make it dynamically to always get charindex/patindex for the very last parentheses. This is what I have so far:

```
DECLARE @str TABLE ( varString VARCHAR(100) );

INSERT  INTO @str
        ( varString )
VALUES  ( 'Hello World (111)' ),
        ( 'Welcome to the World (GI 135) (222)' ),
        ( 'Another Hello World String (ID 12) (141) (333)' );

SELECT  varString
       ,Parsed = CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9])%', varString) - PATINDEX('%([0-9]%', varString) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(varString, PATINDEX('%([0-9]%', varString) + 1, PATINDEX('%[0-9])%', varString) - PATINDEX('%([0-9]%', varString))
                      ELSE NULL
                 END
FROM    @str;
```

but it only works for the first case `Hello World (111)`.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I have it.

```
SELECT  varString
       ,Parsed = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(varString), 2, CHARINDEX('(', REVERSE(varString)) - 2))
FROM    @str;
```

But if there is any other solution based on finding occurrence of last charindex, I will be happy if you share it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reverse and get the latest as below:

```
Select *, Replace(substring(txt,len(txt) - charindex('(', Reverse(txt))+2, len(txt)), ')', '')
from #yourtext
```

Answer (score 0):

handling the string as xml could be another solution to get the last, basically replacing the brackets by tags, cast as xml and get the last element:

```
select cast(replace(replace(varstring,'(','<n>'),')','</n>') as xml).query('//n[last()]/text()')
```

Comment: That's pretty nice. Thanks. Good idea.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you posted requires the string to end with a right parentheses, even a trailing space will kill it.

The XML solution is excellent (brilliant use of the last() function @Jayvee) but will easily break by adding or subtracting a single right or left parentheses.

Below are two solutions that will work and can be easily modified by people looking to retrieve say, the *first* group of numbers or *all* of the sets of numbers. The first solution uses [PatterSplitCM](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/String+Manipulation/94365/) and the second uses [NGrams8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/142316/). Updated sample data and both solutions below.

```
DECLARE @str TABLE (stringId int identity, varString VARCHAR(100) );

INSERT INTO @str(varstring)
VALUES  ( 'Hello World (111)' ),
        ( 'Welcome to the World (GI 135) (222)' ),
        ( 'Another Hello World String (ID 12) (141) (333)' ),
        ( 'Hello World (55555).' ), -- added a period (.)
        ( 'Welcome to the World (GI 135) (999) and smile (:' ), -- add unclosed parentheses,
        ( 'Another Hello World String (ID 1212) (14111) (33333)) ' ), -- ends with a space
        ('No numbers here. Sorry.')

-- SOLUTION #1 (using PatternSplitCM)
SELECT stringId, varString, item 
FROM 
(
  SELECT stringId, varString, item, 
         rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY varstring ORDER BY itemnumber DESC)
  FROM @str
  CROSS APPLY dbo.PatternSplitCM(varString, '[0-9]')
  WHERE [Matched] = 1
) x
WHERE rn = 1
--ORDER BY stringId;
;
-- SOLUTION #2 (using NGrams8K)
SELECT stringId, varString, item 
FROM 
(
  SELECT stringId, varString,
         item = SUBSTRING
                (
                  varString, 
                  position+1, 
                  CHARINDEX(')', varString, position+1)-(position+1)
                ),
         rn  = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY varstring ORDER BY position DESC)
  FROM @str
  CROSS APPLY dbo.ngrams8k(varString,1)
  WHERE token = '('
  AND CHARINDEX(')', varString, position+1) > 0 -- exclude strings without closing parenthesis 
) x
WHERE rn = 1
```

Each query returns:

```
stringId  varString                                             item  
--------- ----------------------------------------------------- ----------
1         Hello World (111)                                     111
2         Welcome to the World (GI 135) (222)                   222
3         Another Hello World String (ID 12) (141) (333)        333
4         Hello World (55555).                                  55555
5         Welcome to the World (GI 135) (999) and smile (:      999
6         Another Hello World String (ID 1212) (14111) (33333)) 33333
```

Comment: Thanks for other suggestion. In my prod I also case the code like: CASE WHEN varString LIKE '%([0-9]%[0-9])%'  THEN ... so it should protect it from the problem you mentioned.